# How to list all the URI of all documents in a directory in marklogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic

Hi how can i retrieve the URI of all the documents in directory. I create the below xquery to achieve that but that doesn't helps.

```
for $i in xdmp:directory("/Test/performance/results/","infinity")
let $k := document-uri(fn:doc($i))
return <li>{$k}</li>
```

Answer (score 12):

For efficiency you should use the URI lexicon.

```
cts:uris((), (), cts:directory-query("/Test/performance/results/","infinity"))
```

See https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:uris for documentation.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
xdmp:directory("/Test/performance/results/","infinity") !
    <li>{fn:document-uri(.)}</li>
```

Comment: Nice use of SMO. Or `xdmp:directory("/Test/performance/results/","infinity")/document-uri(.)/element li { . }` should also work.

Comment: Sure, but personally I find the SMO (Simple Map Operator) approach much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

The posters XQuery is incorrect because $i is already a document not a URI 
so running fn:doc($i) is not going to work.

Adam's solution will work (to infinate depth) but can be very slow as it requires
fetching every document.  On large databases thats very slow.

If you enable the URI Lexicon then you can do much better.
Here is the source for the xmlsh marklogic "ls" command ... embedded in it is fairly simple XQuery.

https://github.com/DALDEI/xmlsh/blob/master/extensions/marklogic/src/org/xmlsh/marklogic/ls.xsh

The relevent code:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare variable $root external;
for $p in fn:distinct-values( 
    for $d in cts:uris($root,"document", 
          if( $root eq "" ) then () else cts:directory-query($root,"infinity"))
    let $p := substring-after( $d , $root )
    where $d ne $root 
    return 
       if( contains($p,"/") ) then fn:concat($root , substring-before( $p , "/" ) , "/" )
    else 
       concat($root ,$p) 
    )
where $p eq "" or $p ne $root
return $p
```

This lists only the direct children of a directory using the uri lexicon

This program is a bit more complex - it tries to use the uri lexicon but if it fails reverts to the xdmp:directory ... it lists either direct or recursive depending on the -r flag

https://github.com/DALDEI/xmlsh/blob/master/extensions/marklogic/src/org/xmlsh/marklogic/list.xsh

Comment: Does it really require fetching every document? I had rather hoped that ML would be clever enough to optimise that away.